# K&R:C - Stack smashing detected

Tags: c, stack-corruption

My code is like this:

```
int find_test(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[MAX_LINES];
    int c, except = 0, found = 0, number = 0;
    long lineno = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-'){
        while(c = *++argv[0]){
            switch(c){
                case 'x':
                    except = 1;
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    number = 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("find:illegal option %c\n", c);
                    argc = 0;
                    found = -1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(argc != 1){
        printf("Usage:find -x -n pattern\n");
    }else{
        while(getline(line, MAX_LENGTH) > 0){
            lineno++;
            if((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except){
                if(number)
                    printf("%ld:", lineno);
                printf("%s\n", line);
                found++;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

`getline` like this:

```
int getline(char *line, int maxline)
{
    char *p = line;
    int c;

    while(maxline-- && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){
        *line++ = c;
    }
    if(maxline > 0)
        *line = '\0';

    return line - p;
}
```

When I use `gcc -Wall -O2 -g a.c -o a.out`, and execute `a.out -x -n 111<find_test`, where `find_test` is just my test data:

```
line1:111111111111111
line2:222222222222222
line3:222222222222222
line4:444444444444444
line2:kasdskskdk
```

I got the error message:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x48)[0xb7ead138]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x0)[0xb7ead0f0]
./a.out[0x8048e95]
./a.out[0x8048ec2]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe0)[0xb7dd6450]
./a.out[0x8048641]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 17488      /home/jyc/prgm/the_c_p_l/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:08 17488      /home/jyc/prgm/the_c_p_l/a.out
0804b000-0806c000 rw-p 0804b000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7dbf000-b7dc0000 rw-p b7dbf000 00:00 0 
b7dc0000-b7f09000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 694644     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so
b7f09000-b7f0a000 r--p 00149000 08:08 694644     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so
b7f0a000-b7f0c000 rw-p 0014a000 08:08 694644     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so
b7f0c000-b7f0f000 rw-p b7f0c000 00:00 0 
b7f0f000-b7f32000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 694648     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.7.so
b7f32000-b7f34000 rw-p 00023000 08:08 694648     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.7.so
b7f3a000-b7f44000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 677855     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7f44000-b7f45000 rw-p 0000a000 08:08 677855     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7f45000-b7f49000 rw-p b7f45000 00:00 0 
b7f49000-b7f4a000 r-xp b7f49000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7f4a000-b7f64000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 678556     /lib/ld-2.7.so
b7f64000-b7f66000 rw-p 00019000 08:08 678556     /lib/ld-2.7.so
bfa26000-bfa3b000 rw-p bffeb000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

but if I use `gcc -Wall -O2 -g -fno-stack-protector a.c -o a.out` and execute `a.out -x -n 111<find_test` everything is ok. I could't find the reason. Can anyone help?

Comment: sorry,the code is a little much,and when i post,it always hint me "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."

Comment: +1 @rld the font is too small on the screenshot, and i seem to find no way to view the screenshot in a bigger resolution... why make it trivial? EDIT: You don't have to paste the full code if it's irrelvent, where it fails is what matters. (aka where you call getline...)

Comment: Why are you using `MAX_LENGTH` `while(getline(line, MAX_LENGTH) > 0){` but you declare `char line[MAX_LINES]` on the stack? notice the MAX_LINES

Comment: About the stack protector: its purpose is to make stack overflows difficult to ignore, ie the mistake is still there, except without it you don't notice it by pure luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up `MAX_LINES` and `MAX_LENGTH`. Looks like you allocate space for the former, but what you read in is the latter.

```
int find_test(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[MAX_LINES];            <-------------
    int c...

    ....

    while(getline(line, MAX_LENGTH) > 0){  <-------
```

BTW, why don't you use `fgets()` instead of `getline()`?

### Update

> but,if i use gcc -Wall -O2 -g -fno-stack-protector a.c -o a.out,and
>   execute a.out -x -n 111 < find_test, everything is ok

**No.** Most definitely everything is *not* OK. You are *still* overwriting a memory area; the overwrite may be "mostly harmless" *now* and on *this* specific platform, but it is still potentially lethal. In another context, the same error, unless some protection were in place (luckily, nowadays it very often is -- but you can't count on *luck*!) might [allow a remote attacker to gain control of your machine](https://www.google.it/search?q=stack%20smashing%20attack). If you were to try with longer lines, chances are that your "OK" program with no stack protector would segfault again (or, for more complex programs, return incorrect results or even cause damage to the system).

Answer (score 2):

When you line reaches `MAX_LENGTH` your `strstr` can scan beyond the buffer because the buffer doesn't have a '\0' character.

EDIT: And there is even another point I would like to make. That one is controversial because there are arguments for both possibilities. It would be better to use `unsigned` buffer indexes in my opinion. This would force to handle the loop differently, which is imho easier to get right. Furthermore when indexing an array with an `unsigned`, in case of underflowing you will get more likely a `segmentation fault` with it than with a signed integral.
We had the case in our project recently (a system that is in production since 1998) and I changed one variable in the code to a `size_t` and catched 2 underflow bugs that have been missed since the beginning.

EDIT2: Another stylistic point I want to make. Avoid post-(in|de)crement in loop expressions, they very often lead to subtle bugs (like the one above). Pre-(in|de)crement is not a problem. The reason post-(in|de)crement are problematic is that when you mentally parse the expression for its conditions (continue or break), it is immediately invalid, i.e. at then end of the expression, the values that you used in your head to see the result are no longer existing. Maybe it's only me, but in the 25 years I programmed in C, there were a huge number of times I got post-(in|de)crement in loops wrong and it was always corrected by either pre-(in|de)crementing or lifting the incrementation out of the boolean expression.

Comment: Oops, I haven't seen Iserni answer. I don't delete my response because it addresses another problem.

Comment: And I hadn't seen the problem that you report, which could lead to a yet different crash. +1 for proving Linus' Law.

Comment: Which Linus' law? Do you have a reference? I'm curious and I love his insights.

Comment: "Given enough eyeballs, all bugs are shallow" - that's Eric S. Raymond ("The Cathedral and the Bazaar"), but he called it "Linus' Law".

Comment: @tristopia,thx to your share, i don't understand the `EDIT2`:why post-(in|de) is better than pre-(in|de),can u write an example code?thanks.

Comment: It's all about code reading. When reading code I tend to evaluate the expressions in my head. With pre-(dec|inc) the value computed is the one used in the boolean expression and is the value that the variable contains in the body of the loop. With post-(inc|dec) the value used in the expression and the value stored in the variable in the loop body differ. It is mentally a little bit more complex imho. In a simple example of course, it's not a big deal, but when you read a lot of code, as I do, it is more error prone.